# Largest Useful Sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm just asking this out of curiosity, what are the largest sets that are actually meaningful (infinite sets)? I know that there is no highest cardinal number, but there must come a point where we cannot actually find any interesting set of that size. The largest I can think of is the set of functions from $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, but this is just the power set of $\mathbb R$ and so not particularly big.

Comment: What about the set of quaternion functions $\Bbb H \to \Bbb H$

Comment: To me "useful", "meaningful", "interesting", and (as you say in the comments to Asaf's answer) "explicitly definable" are four completely different things!  So I am a bit confused about what your question is.

Comment: Do measurable cardinals satisfy any of your criteria? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, define useful.

The notion of large cardinals, which are sets so large that you cannot even begin to understand how large they are, and then there are even larger large cardinals, is useful. The current known proof of Fermat's Last Theorem uses these cardinals, or rather an equivalent concept called "universes".

The question whether or not all "nicely definable" sets of real numbers have certain properties are also determined by the existence of fairly huge sets in the universe.

And that is before we talk about uses of large cardinals in set theory, or model theory, or the weird appearances of very large cardinals in homotopy theory.

That been said, of course that if your definition of interesting is "what they do in classical measure theory/functional analysis/classical analysis/classical number theory and not a tiny bit of generality more!" then it is true that it's hard to see the point of using sets larger than the continuum, or at most its power set.

Finally, let me just point out that we can't even decide how large is $2^{\aleph_0}$ from the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, and certainly not $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ either. So both can be fairly large in terms of $\aleph$ numbers, but of course neither is even remotely as large as the least inaccessible cardinal (which is the smallest notion of a large cardinal).

Comment: Thanks, by useful I really mean ones which can be explicitly defined, and intersting by not just creating a large set by, for example, taking the power set a load of times.

Comment: Again, the existence of very large cardinals can affect the behavior of sets of real numbers (with terms of measurability, etc.). If that is not an interesting use for sets, then I'm not sure what is. Moreover large cardinals are exactly those that **cannot** be obtained by iterating the power set a lot of times.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a particular set whose cardinality is one of these large cardinals?

Comment: @user109720: Well a cardinal is a set. Sets are not just sets of real numbers, or sets of sets of real numbers, or sets of sets of sets of sets ... you get the idea. Sets are much much more complicated than that in a lot of ways. And saying "Can you specify a set with this cardinality" is almost meaningless from a set theoretical point, and has a trivial answer -- the cardinal itself.

Comment: I still try to come up with an example of interesting algebraic object witch cardinality is bigger then continuum. Most of constructions i can think of (even inductive) are ending on $\omega_1$.